# Is this a bug in Mac grep? Grep from a file but miss some pattern

Tags: macos, shell, grep

I tried on my Mac(High Sierra 10.13.6). I got a file which contains the following lines:

```
8
89
```

Let's call it a.txt. And I used the command `grep -Fxf a.txt a.txt` But I only got output 8 without 89. 
And it works properly on Linux.

It seems like that mac grep will pop out lines from all candidates once it matched a pattern, so other patterns will not match the same line again.

Comment: Sounds plausible. I'll note that if you use two separate files, with one in reverse order, you do get two lines of output.

Comment: With `-x` is there some non-termination of the final line?

Comment: With one in reverse order, then 89 will be searched first. So 89 will only match 89, and 8 left to be matched by 8.  In original order, 8 will match both 8 and 89, and after `-x` filter 89.  Only 8 will output, but 89 will never be put back to candidates.